# How to override the protected function in abstract class in Magento 2.2.8

Tags: magento2.2

In Magento 2.2.8, I want to override the `CalculateWithTaxInPrice` protected function in the `/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php` file.

I tried using the plugin and preference but the function was not overridden.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento Plugin only work for public functions.

For your case, I recommend using Observer if possible, else you can use preferences.